# Find the position of when a particular sequence occurs in a string using a sliding window in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, window, find, position

If there's a window list

```
text='abcdefg'
window_list=[text[i:i+3] for i in range(len(text)-3)]
print window_list
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def']

for i in window_list:
    for j,k in zip(range(len(text)),i):
    print j,k
0 a
1 b
2 c
0 b
1 c
2 d
0 c
1 d
2 e
0 d
1 e
2 f
```

i'm trying to make it so when

```
(j==0 and k=='c') and (j==1 and k=='d') and (j==2 and k=='e')
```

it would give me the starts and ending position where that occurs on the string text

so it would give me

```
[2-4]
```

Comment: What exactly are you upto? (Explain it properly, I would remove the "-1")

Comment: I'm trying to scan through a particular sequence (text) and if it fits the input sequence ('cde') i want it to give me the range of the original sequence that it covers. so if its 'abcdefg' the result would be [2-5] or [2-4] (whatever range that it is) if the sequence was 'abbbbbbcdef' the return value would be different . basically the main thing is that it has to be in that order . my ideal way to do it would to check if the position 0 was 'c', the position 1 was 'd', and the position 2 was 'e'

Comment: you need to improve your question by editing your question and adding this explanation there, once done i would give 2+ :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought to do it in this way?

```
>>> text='abcdefg'
>>> window_list=[text[i:i+3] for i in range(len(text)-3)]
>>> ["-".join([str(i),str(i+len(w))]) for i,w in enumerate(window_list) if w == 'cde'] #for single item
['2-5']
>>> ["-".join([str(i),str(i+len(w))]) for i,w in enumerate(window_list) if w in ['cde','def']] # for multiple items
['2-5', '3-6']
>>>
```

Note: [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)  the list and search for those items which matches the condition. Return the index followed by the end position (which is index + length of the sub-sequence). Please note, the result would be a string rather than what you are expecting.

Comment: would that still work if the sequence was text='abbbbbeeeecdefbbbbbb' ? or is it searching for the particular values 2-5 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
seq = 'abcdefabcdefabcdefg'
for match in re.finditer('abc', seq):
    print match.start(), match.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

All you need to do is find if your pattern is in the doc or not. This can be done easily using Python in built string "find" function. Once you find the start position of your string, then all you need to do is add the length of your pattern to get end position. thats it! job done ;)

**The Code:**

```
text = "abcdefghifjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
start_position = text.find("abc")
if(start_position>-1):
    end_position = start_position+len(start_position) - 1
else:
    print "Pattern not found"
print start_position, "-", end_position
```

**The Output:**

```
0 - 2
```

**Reference:**
Check Official Python String Functions Documentation